# Share & Embed Widget design samples?

Tags: interface, widget

I am searching for some sample interface or design for creating a "Share & Embed Widget or Link" interface in my website.

I found scribd.com's interface interesting http://www.scribd.com/doc/22735617/Senate-Health-Care-Bill here click on "Share & Embed" link given in top-right of the doc.

Could any one please provide me some sample links of website who provides this kind of interfaces, or any blog post related to this topic, so that I can take inspiration from those interfaces to design my "Sharing widget" interface.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Interface patterns:

[UI Pattern Factory](http://uipatternfactory.com/)

[12 Usefull Interface Designs](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/01/19/12-useful-techniques-for-good-user-interface-design-in-web-applications/)

[Designing Web Interfaces](http://www.flickr.com/photos/designingwebinterfaces/sets/)

Hope this works for you.